# Python import fonts from font list

Tags: python, list, python-import

I am beginning to think that I cannot use Python import in this way.

```
font_list = [
  'HIRANGANA_FONT',
  'GREEK_FONT',
  'EXT_LATIN_FONT',
  'CONTROL_FONT',
  'BOX_FONT',
  'BLOCK_FONT',
  'BASIC_LATIN_FONT',
  'CP437_FONT_ROT90',
  'CP437_FONT_ROT180',
  'CP437_FONT_ROT270',
  'VINCENT_FONT',
  'CP437_FONT',
  'SINCLAIRS_FONT',
  'LCD_FONT',
  'TINY_FONT',
];

from fonts_file import i for i in font_list
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So I try:

```
for i in font_list:
  from fonts_file import i
```

> ImportError: cannot import name i

Is it possible?
Can I import everything in font_list from one line of code?

I know this below works, but I am trying to keep things left justified

```
from fonts_file import HIRANGANA_FONT, GREEK_FONT, EXT_LATIN_FONT, CONTROL_FONT, BOX_FONT, BLOCK_FONT, BASIC_LATIN_FONT....
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `import` in that way at all? You can always use `getattr(fonts_file, i)` to refer to the font whose name is stored in variable `i`; there's nothing special you need the `from module import name` syntax for. (Then again, I wouldn't want to stuff them into your module namespace at all; what's the value to `CP437_FONT` as a word you can use in your code, vs `import fonts_file as f` and then referring to `f.CP327_FONT`?)

Comment: What about something like: `import fonts_file as ff`.  The use `ff.GREEK_FONT` when you need to use it?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything that works well. I am a novice and I have some python code that I am working with and trying to make it better. So I'll give both those a shot and see how life is. Thanks.

Comment: @WesZ I strongly recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general, before anything else.

Comment: Thanks AMC, but this really isn't my professional job and I honestly don't use it to feed my family. A year ago I knew nothing of Python... but like I said, Thanks for the advice, but I assure you that I am learning...unless you think asking questions is not part of the learning process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from fonts_file import (HIRANGANA_FONT,
                        GREEK_FONT,
                        EXT_LATIN_FONT,
                        CONTROL_FONT,
                        ...
                        )
```

Comment: I'd probably put a newline continuation before the first font name to allow those names to be sorted automatically (as with `!sort` in vim). The OP isn't doing that now, but they *should* -- it'll make for fewer merge conflicts if they're merging multiple branches that each change the list, should that list be maintained in a consistent way.

Comment: Well Scott, that was "Slick 'n Quick" there buddy !! I used Charles' suggestion as well with a preceding \ and it's all good to go. No code changes, updates, etc. All just a nice neat package all dressed left. Thanks Guys !!